Can't deploy Vue app (Vite v6.0.3) on Vercel because of tailwind.config
During deploying,Vue 3.5 composition API (Vite v6.0.3) app on Vercel (It works fine on Netlify) I'm getting that error because of tailwind, I also have 3 tsconfigs, I will paste them below:
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js:1:17
    at ModuleJobSync.runSync (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:395:35)
    at ModuleLoader.importSyncForRequire (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:47)
    at loadESMFromCJS (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1547:5)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1677:16)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:219:24)
Node.js v22.12.0
error: script "build" exited with code 1
Error: Command "bun run build" exited with 1

Even thought everything works without any problems locally, even if I change require to ES6 modules the new error appear:
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at file:///vercel/path0/tailwind.config.js:5:1
    at ModuleJobSync.runSync (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:395:35)
    at ModuleLoader.importSyncForRequire (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:47)
    at loadESMFromCJS (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1547:5)
    at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1677:16)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1318:32)
    at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1128:12)
    at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
    at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:219:24)
Node.js v22.12.0
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

import animate from "tailwindcss-animate";
import tailwindHamburgers from "tailwind-hamburgers";

tailwind.config.js:
const tailwindHamburgers = require("tailwind-hamburgers");

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  safelist: ["dark"],
  prefix: "",
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}",
    "./components/**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}",
    "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}",
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx,vue}",
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: "2rem",
      screens: {
        "2xl": "1400px",
      },
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        "main-black": "#141522",
        "main-purple": {
          100: "#DCE4FF",
          200: "#BAC8FF",
          300: "#98ABFF",
          400: "#7E95FF",
          500: "#546FFF",
          600: "#3D53DB",
          700: "#2A3BB7",
          800: "#1A2793",
          900: "#10197A",
        },
        border: "hsl(var(--border))",
        input: "hsl(var(--input))",
        ring: "hsl(var(--ring))",
        background: "hsl(var(--background))",
        foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--primary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--primary-foreground))",
        },
        secondary: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--secondary))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))",
        },
        destructive: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--destructive))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))",
        },
        muted: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--muted))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--muted-foreground))",
        },
        accent: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--accent))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--accent-foreground))",
        },
        popover: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--popover))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--popover-foreground))",
        },
        card: {
          DEFAULT: "hsl(var(--card))",
          foreground: "hsl(var(--card-foreground))",
        },
      },
      borderRadius: {
        skeleton: "calc(var(--radius) + 12px)",
        xl: "calc(var(--radius) + 4px)",
        "lg-max": "calc(var(--radius) + 2px)",
        lg: "var(--radius)",
        md: "calc(var(--radius) - 2px)",
        sm: "calc(var(--radius) - 4px)",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "accordion-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
        },
        "accordion-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-accordion-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
        "collapsible-down": {
          from: { height: 0 },
          to: { height: "var(--radix-collapsible-content-height)" },
        },
        "collapsible-up": {
          from: { height: "var(--radix-collapsible-content-height)" },
          to: { height: 0 },
        },
        spin: {
          "0%": { transform: "rotate(0deg)" },
          "100%": { transform: "rotate(360deg)" },
        },
      },
      animation: {
        spin: "spin 1s linear infinite",
        "accordion-down": "accordion-down 0.2s ease-out",
        "accordion-up": "accordion-up 0.2s ease-out",
        "collapsible-down": "collapsible-down 0.2s ease-in-out",
        "collapsible-up": "collapsible-up 0.2s ease-in-out",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [animate, tailwindHamburgers],
};

tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"]
}

tsconfig.json:
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    { "path": "./tsconfig.app.json" },
    { "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }
  ]
}

tsconfig.node.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": ["ES2023"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "noEmit": true,

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedSideEffectImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}

vite.config.ts
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";
import tailwind from "tailwindcss";

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwind, autoprefixer],
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});


module.exports is not ESM tho, rewrite your Tailwind config properly. Write everything in ESM and set module in your package.json.
